# Windows removedrive.exe isn't working

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, usb

I'm trying to use RemoveDrive.exe to safely remove usb through command line.

The command is

```
D:/softwares/removedrive/RemoveDrive.exe G:
```

But, I'm getting the following error

```
RemoveDrive V2.8.4 (x64) - prepares drive for safe removal
Freeware by Uwe Sieber - www.uwe-sieber.de
Removing 'Mass Storage Drive USB Device (G:)
Veto=TypeUnknown
failed
```

I searched the internet, but nothing found. Can someone help me on this. I need to remove the usb disk through command line

Comment: no answer to the question, but you could use PowerShell so you don't need 3rd party tools. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/417345-powershell-script-to-eject-usb-device

Comment: also, for your current problem: try to add the `-L` switch. `D:/softwares/removedrive/RemoveDrive.exe G: -L` and also the x64 version, if you've got that